# Python SciPy UnivariateSpline returns NaN - value in range

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use SciPy's `UnivariateSpline` to locate a point on a curve. Unfortunately, my result is `nan`.
Here's a minimal example:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline  

spline = UnivariateSpline([0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0], [-0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3], w=None, bbox=[None, None], k=1, s=0)  
POINT = spline([0.15])  
print POINT
```

The result is `[ NaN]`.
Which feature of `UnivariateSpline` did I miss?

I'm using Python 2.6.6 and scipy version 0.7.2

I cannot guarantee that I have always increasing datapoints so `interp` might not be an alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [docstring for UnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) states, the values in `x` must be increasing.  You'll have to sort your data if you want to use UnivariateSpline.  E.g. something like this:

```
In [71]: x = np.array([0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0])

In [72]: y = np.array([-0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3])

In [73]: order = np.argsort(x)

In [74]: spline = UnivariateSpline(x[order], y[order], w=None, bbox=[None, None], k=1, s=0)

In [75]: spline([0.15])
Out[75]: array([ 0.15])
```